# In F#, how can I turn a list of continuations into a continuation that takes a list?

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming, continuations, continuation-passing

First some context: I'm playing around with `KFoldTree` from [this excellent blog post](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/05/31/catamorphisms-part-five/). I have a tree structure that is n-ary instead of binary. With a binary tree, applying the CPS transform to the function you pass to `KFoldTree` is not too hard. You end up with something like:

```
kleft (fun left -> kright (fun right -> k (dosomethingwith left right)))
```

The problem with an n-ary tree is that you have to construct this chain of continuations on-the-fly. What you want to end up with should look something like this:

```
kchildren (fun children -> k (dosomethingwith children))
```

where `children` is a list of the result type of the fold. For example, if I'm writing a pretty-printer, `children` should be of type `string list`, while `kchildren` should be of type `(string list -> string) -> string`.

So how do we define a function that produces `kchildren`, given a `((Node -> string) -> string) list` (to continue the pretty-printer example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
let chain continuations cont =
    let rec loop acc =
        function
        | k::ks -> k (fun x -> loop (x::acc) ks)
        | [] -> cont acc
    // Reverse the input list to preserve original left-to-right order.
    List.rev continuations |> loop []
```

Is there a better way?